# Showing a certain span of complex matrices closed under multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix. Consider $M=\text{span}(T^k:1\leq k \leq n^2)$. I'm trying to show that $M$ is closed under multiplication.

I've of course tried just writing up two standard elements and multiplying them together, but that doesn't work out very nicely. My idea is maybe we can write it in another basis where it is easier to show, but I haven't gotten any specific ideas.  Does anyone have a tip or a proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation can be $1\le k<n$, because, by the Hamilton-Cayley theorem, $T$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial, which has degree $n$.

So, if the characteristic polynomial is 
$$
p_T(X)=\det(T-XI)=a_0+a_1X+\dots+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+(-1)^nX^n
$$
we can write
$$
T^n=(-1)^{n+1}(a_0I+a_1T+\dots+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}).
$$
Therefore we can prove by easy induction that, for all $m\ge0$,
$$
T^{n+m}=q_m(T)
$$
for some polynomial $q_m(X)$ of degree at most $n-1$.

Now, write two elements of $\operatorname{span}(T^k:1\le k<n)$ and multiply them, reducing elements as you go.